# ¿como obtener coordenadas en un hilo secundario?

Tags: java, android-studio, hilos

Si ejecuto obtenerCoordenadas() en el hilo principal, funciona bien (obtengo las coordenadas incluso cuando se cambia de posicion),

Si ejecuto runThread() solo, funciona bien

Si ejecuto obtenerCoordenadas dentro de runThread(), no funciona se bloquea y se sale.

¿Como puedo adaptar el código obtenerCoordenadas para que me funcione dentro de runThread? y así obtener las coordenadas en un hilo aparte al principal.

Quiero obterner las coordenadas en un hilo secundario, porque si las obtengo en el principal y las coordenadas cambian muy rapido se bloquea la aplicación

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//  obtenerCoordenadas();   

runThread();    

}

 
private void runThread() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            obtenerCoordenadas();

            //Inicio actualizacion hilo principal
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Coordenadas: " +latitude+" "+longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });
                    //Fin actualizacion hilo principal

        }
    }).start();
}


public void obtenerCoordenadas() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);
    }

    latlon = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location loca = latlon.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (loca != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A-lat: "+loca.getLatitude()+" \n A-lon: "+loca.getLongitude()+" \n ALT: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    LocationListener locationListener;

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            LocationListener.super.onStatusChanged(provider, status, extras);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {
            LocationListener.super.onProviderEnabled(provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
            LocationListener.super.onProviderDisabled(provider);
        }
    };

    latlon.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,100,locationListener);

}
```

Comment: Es muy complicada mi pregunta, no tiene solución o esta mal formulada? alguien me puede orientar por favor

Comment: Hola a todos, ¿esta mal formulada mi pregunta, no se puede hacer lo que quiero hacer?,alguien me puede colaborar o sugerir algo por favor, gracias